# Enabling Spring Security header causing slow page load in IE11

Tags: spring, spring-security, internet-explorer-11, content-security-policy

I have enable Spring Security header.
But in IE11 page is loads very slow.
It's like first full white screen comes for 1-2 sec then page is loaded.

My code is like this:

```xml
<security:headers disabled="false">
     <security:content-security-policy policy-directives="script-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'" />
     <security:cache-control disabled="true"/>
</security:headers>
```

In Firefox it's working fine but in IE11 its loading slowly.
Also I checked in IE11 headers getting added in response is different. One extra tag i.e. `Etag` is getting added in IE11 but in Firefox it's not getting added.
What could be the reason for slowness?

Comment: Hi, did you already try add it to: Tools>Compatibility View Settings>Add this website ?

Comment: Also check https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/3770 maybe it will be useful